# Where are update operators constants in MongoDB Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, operators, constants

I'm going to use `mongo-java-driver-3.8.0` on my application and I just started studying the documentation to use it in a proper way.
The class `com.mongodb.QueryOperators` has constants for the operators to be used in queries, as you can see in the [MongoDB API Javadoc](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/constant-values.html) .

Is there somewhere an analogous class storing constants for [Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/)? I don't understand if I'm not able to find them or simply they don't exist (in this case I would like to understand why).

Comment: is that spring application or simple java application to interact with Mongo DB

Comment: It's a telegram bot, but I'm actually testing my knowledge of mongo with a simple Main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no constants for update operations because there is no need for them. The package `com.mongodb.client.model.Updates` provides a full set of functions that will create an update that performs the required operation with the given parameters ([documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Updates.html)).

Answer (score 1):

ok, I share a link to just download in Github.
Download example from here and grow up your knowledge. if you have any issue to set up please let me know.
https://github.com/faizakram/SpringWithMongoDB